# routing eth0:1 directly to kvm VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, dedicated-server, ip-routing, eth0

Ive got a Dedicated Server with 2 Public IP Adresses and would like to route all eth0:1 traffic to a KVM Guest via iproute2 or even iptables. Outgoing Traffic should also be routed to eth0:1 - eth0 and eth0:1 are assigned in different Subnets.

Setup is/should be as following:
178.1.2.3 eth0:1 <-> 192.168.1.254 br1, gateway for tap1 <-> 192.168.1.1 KVM Guest

Answer (score 5):

This seems way too complex. Just bridge the VM and set the IP address in the guest.

Answer (score -1):

it actually was surprisingly simple:

```
-A PREROUTING -d 178.1.2.3/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.1/32 -j SNAT --to-source 178.1.2.3
```

thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah, and now you have completely unnecessary NAT which is going to make your life more difficult later. :)